# Rsync is syncing $HOME instead of the provided directory

Tags: bash, rsync

Any idea why this rsync command could be syncing contents of a home directory instead of the actual path provided?

```
echo "\${REMOTE_STORAGE_PATH}: ${REMOTE_STORAGE_PATH}/files/"

rsync -zqr -e "ssh -p ${REMOTE_PORT}" --delete ${REMOTE_USER}@${REMOTE_SERVER}:"${REMOTE_STORAGE_PATH}/files/" "${FILES_PATH}"
```

`REMOTE_STORAGE_PATH`have a correct value (`/var/storage`), files I want to sync are in `/var/storage/files`. Yet, what is being synced is a content of the home directory of my `REMOTE_USER`. Like... what even can cause this? Any ideas?

`REMOTE_USER` is the owner of the `REMOTE_STORAGE_PATH` directory, and `files` subdirectory.

Actually, the most baffling part is that in the same script, almost just before that, I have almost exactly the same line of code:

```
rsync -zqr -e "ssh -p ${REMOTE_PORT}" --delete --progress ${REMOTE_USER}@${REMOTE_SERVER}:"${REMOTE_STORAGE_PATH}/database.sql" "${DUMPS_PATH}/${TARGET}.sql"
```

And that syncs correctly. Like... what?

Comment: Did you run the script with `bash -x` to see what the actual command used looks like?

Comment: It looks fine: `+ rsync -zqr -e 'ssh -p 20022' --delete --progress luken@xxx:/var/storage/files/ /home/luken/srv/http/projects/2014/xxx/scripts/../env/dev/php/resources/files` (just censored few bits). And it still synced `$HOME`... (I added `--progress`  as a desperate attempt to make it the same as the previous one, to see if it will change anything, but it shouldn't matter).

Comment: Could you just also have a look at the actual files under `/var/storage/files` on the remote host as a sanity check, just to see whether the files there are the files that you expect to be there?

Comment: OMG, I cannot believe, haha, you were right, although I have no idea how the content of files ended up as it ended. Well, you can post it as an answer I guess, that's the peak of my stupidity this year I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502303/rsync-is-syncing-home-instead-of-the-provided-directory#comment926088_502303).

There was no issue whatsoever with the `rsync` command.  Rather, the remote directory contained files not actually expected to be there.

---

A short note about the command though,

```
rsync -zqr \
    -e "ssh -p ${REMOTE_PORT}" \
    --delete \
    ${REMOTE_USER}@${REMOTE_SERVER}:"${REMOTE_STORAGE_PATH}/files/" \
    "${FILES_PATH}"
```

This contains a number of unquoted variable expansions.  For safety, I would write this as

```
rsync -zqr \
    -e "ssh -p '$REMOTE_PORT'" \
    --delete \
    "$REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_SERVER:$REMOTE_STORAGE_PATH/files/" \
    "$FILES_PATH"
```

Note that using `${variable}` is exactly the same as `$variable` unless the immediately following character is a valid character in a variable name, as in `${variable}x`.

In a script, I would additionally *always* use the long options, if possible, for documentation purposes.  But that's my personal opinion. And I would probably use `--archive` rather than `--recursive`, to also sync file metadata (timestamps etc.)

```
rsync --compress --quiet --archive \
    --rsh="ssh -p '$REMOTE_PORT'" \
    --delete \
    "$REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_SERVER:$REMOTE_STORAGE_PATH/files/" \
    "$FILES_PATH"
```